# Dropbox Daemon install on every startup

Tags: kubuntu, dropbox

I am running Kubuntu 16.04.1.

I installed dropbox and everything is working fine, the only annoying thing is that every time I startup my machine the dropbox daemon installation popup appears and if I do not install it everytime dropbox won't work.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

I installed it via the deb file downloaded from dropbox.com

Comment: How did you installed Dropbox in the first place?

Comment: I installed it using the deb file on dropbox.com

Comment: That perhaps explains it. Dropbox is in the Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with Ubuntu Software or `sudo apt install dropbox` and it works as expected. Try the command above anyway, with the `--reinstall` option if it must.

Comment: @CelticWarrior it worked. please write the answer so I can accept it. Thank you

Comment: Done and expanded. Software in the official repos is audited and tested to work. Most PPAs are trusted (tested and well maintained). Everything else is inherently risky. Dropbox, Steam and many others are generally safe but their distributed packages may not (and often aren't) the best for installing in a given Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox is in the Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with **Ubuntu Software** or

`sudo apt install dropbox`

and it works as expected.

Use with `--reinstall` parameter if it replies with an "already installed" message:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall dropbox
```

Whenever possible always prefer the software already available at the official repositories for your Ubuntu release. When a newer or specific version is required and not available at the official repositories the next best option is to add a trusted PPA. Installing `deb` files from third party websites is always the last resource.